# Character in one string is included in other string

Tags: algorithm

How to verify every character in one string is include in another string.
like, abc is string1, and cbade is string2, all the character in string1(a b c) are all included in string2.
actually it looks simple, but we need fastest way to do that, so still very hard, i spend whole week cannot get one solution.

Comment: What is this for? If it's an interview question then they're probably looking for the hash/lookup table solution (they're actually the same with different hashing functions). If you're really looking for the fastest implementation you can make optimizations to speed it up.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why all the down votes on the answers, particularly without providing an alternate solution. They're all perfectly valid solutions.

Comment: can the 1st string, the one whose characters you want to find in the other, have duplicate characters? If yes, does the other string has to have the same multiplicity (at least) of their occurrences to satisfy the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a language where you can easily assign a character a numeric value (most languages), you can speed this up further with a lookup table:

1. lookup table, one slot for every character
2. visit letters in string2 in lookup table
3. make sure letters in string1 are visited
4. ???
5. profit

Runtime: A + B
Runspace: A + B + N, where N is number of possible characters. (C: 256, Java: 65536)

If you're not, you should be able to establish an arbitrary ordering between characters, in which case:

1. sort both strings alphabetically
2. binary search (you can use the position of the last found match as a really good initial guess)
3. ???
4. profit

Runtime: A*log(A) + B*log(B) + A*log(B)
Runspace: A + B

Comment: This works, but sorting is unnecessarily complex for this problem.

Comment: Set lookup overhead is arguably pricey as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make hash map (of characters mapping to booleans)
2. Iterate over string1, creating an entry in the hash table for each character
3. Iterate over string2, setting the entry in the hash table to true for each character you see
4. Iterate over the elements in the hash map (possible in most implementations I know, should be O(n), i.e. O(A)), stop and return false if you see false entry, else return true

   => 

   Time: O(A+B), A being the length of string1, B of string2

   Space: O(A)

   *Assumptions:* Iteration over string/hashmap: O(n) time, Lookup/insert in hashmap: O(1) [notice those are probably all amortized]

Answer (score -1):

Put all the characters in the two strings into two sets, and then check to see that one is a subset of the other. In Python:

```
>>> set("abc").issubset(set("cbade"))
True
```

Comment: I don't see why anyone downvoted this.  It's a perfectly reasonable way to do it that scales fairly well even to very large strings, with constant runtime and runspace roughly proportional to the complexity of the strings.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in O(n).  First construct a hashtable of the characters present in the second string.  Then iterate over the characters in the first string and assert that that character has an entry in the hashtable.

Answer (score -1):

Because number of possible characters is small (assume 256), you could have a fixed array of size 256, at first set each of its bit to zero, then when you visit any character in the first string set related bit in array, after that traverse second array and if you see there is no bit to set, means all of them were in previous string, you can say all the characters of second string are available in first string, else, if you see a character in second string such that relate bit not set yet, you can say the first string doesn't contain second one. This algorithm is O(n) in time and O(1) in memory (i.e O(1) external memory).